# Randomly Order Posts on WordPress Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code that shows 5 posts each being the latest from an author. Want I want to do is show the these 5 posts in a random order so that no author gets precedence over the other. To clarify this is the ordering of these 5 posts and NOT the posts of the author. Thanks

code:

```
<?PHP

  get_header();

 ?>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $('#post-list').masonry({ singleMode: true, itemSelector: 'article', animate: false });
  });
 </script>

 <?php

  function MyLoopCode()
  {
 ?>

 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

  <div class="post-image"></div>

  <div class="post-text">

  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

  <p class="p-cat">In: <?php the_category('|') ?></p>

  <p class="p-author">
   <span class="name"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
   <span class="avatar"><a title="View posts by <?php the_author(); ?>" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($authordata->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( $email, $size = '64' ); ?></a>
   </span>
  </p>


  <small class="p-time">
  <strong class="day"><?php the_time('j') ?></strong>
  <strong class="month"><?php the_time('M') ?></strong>
  <strong class="year"><?php the_time('Y') ?></strong>
  </small>

  <section class="content">
   <?php the_content('<p>Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
  </section>

  <div class="p-det">
   <p class="p-det-com"><?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '(1) Comment', '(%) Comments'); ?></p>
   <?php if (function_exists('the_tags')) { ?> <?php the_tags('<p class="p-det-tag">Tags: ', ', ', '</p>'); ?> <?php } ?>
  </div>

  </div>

 </article>

 <?php } ?>



   <div id="maincontent" class="clearfix">

    <div class="leftcontent">

     <section id="post-list" class="post-list">

     <?php //query_posts('orderby=rand'); ?>

     <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=2'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php echo MyLoopCode(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

     <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

     <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=3'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php echo MyLoopCode(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

     <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

     <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=4'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php echo MyLoopCode(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

     <article>

      <p>ADVERTISEMENT</p>

     </article>

     <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

     <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=5'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php echo MyLoopCode(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

     <?php rewind_posts(); ?>

     <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=6'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <?php echo MyLoopCode(); ?>

     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

     </section>

    </div>
    <!-- END div.leftcontent -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

   </div>
   <!-- END div#maincontent -->



 <?PHP

  get_footer();

 ?>
```

Comment: Was going to suggest using `ORDER BY RAND()` somewhere in there, but I see this has been added / commented out at some point.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work when you're calling multiple queries as I'm not ordering the query results, but ordering the queries themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:**
1. Get output of `MyLoopCode()` as an array.
2. Shuffle the array.
3. Display contents.

---

**Implementation:**

1) Return the output of `MyLoopCode()` using [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/ob_get_clean)  & store it in an array.

*Explanation:* The `ob_start()` starts output caching so instead of sending the output to the browser the PHP will keep the output in its buffer. Then, at the end of the function, by using `ob_get_clean()`, we tell PHP to give use the output as a string and delete from its buffer. So, the function now returns the contents that would be otherwise outputted to the browser by the `MyLoopCode()` function.

```
<?php
 function MyLoopCode()
  {
ob_start();
 ?>

 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

  <div class="post-image"></div>

  <div class="post-text">

  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

  <p class="p-cat">In: <?php the_category('|') ?></p>

  <p class="p-author">
   <span class="name"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span>
   <span class="avatar"><a title="View posts by <?php the_author(); ?>" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($authordata->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( $email, $size = '64' ); ?></a>
   </span>
  </p>


  <small class="p-time">
  <strong class="day"><?php the_time('j') ?></strong>
  <strong class="month"><?php the_time('M') ?></strong>
  <strong class="year"><?php the_time('Y') ?></strong>
  </small>

  <section class="content">
   <?php the_content('<p>Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
  </section>

  <div class="p-det">
   <p class="p-det-com"><?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '(1) Comment', '(%) Comments'); ?></p>
   <?php if (function_exists('the_tags')) { ?> <?php the_tags('<p class="p-det-tag">Tags: ', ', ', '</p>'); ?> <?php } ?>
  </div>

  </div>

 </article>

 <?php
  return ob_get_clean();
  } ?>
```

2) Now, instead of `echo`ing the output directly, as I said save it in an array:

*Explanation:* Everytime the `MyLoopCode()` function is called, it output is now stored in the array `$myarray`. So, NO output is sent to the browser yet.

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&author=2'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php $myarray[] = MyLoopCode(); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

After all these function calls, the content of `$myarray` will look like (pseudo-code):

```
myarray[0] = user1-post1 + user1-post2 + user1-post3 + user1-post4 + user1-post5;  
myarray[1] = user2-post1 + user2-post2 + user2-post3 + user2-post4 + user2-post5;  
myarray[2] = user3-post1 + user3-post2 + user3-post3 + user3-post4 + user3-post5;  
myarray[3] = user4-post1 + user4-post2 + user4-post3 + user4-post4 + user4-post5;  
myarray[4] = user5-post1 + user5-post2 + user5-post3 + user5-post4 + user5-post5;
```

3) Now, randomize the array contents using [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle) and display them:

*Explanation:* The `shuffle()` function randomizes the contents of the `$myarray`. Since this array contains all the posts by individual user, what really happens is that the posts-user groups are randomized. Finally traverse the array by foreach and echo the contents.

```
 <?php
  shuffle($myarray);

  foreach($myarray as $x)
        echo $x;
 ?>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this works, but it seems to be doing the trick. Would you be able to explain a bit more of what each line does so I can learn from it. Thanks.

Comment: @Cameron, I have explained every step. Please upvote and accept the answer if this works for you.